# Toggle parent element's class jQuery based on HREF value

Tags: jquery, class, html-lists, toggle, href

As you may tell I am learning jQuery today (amongst other web stuff).

I am trying to neatly change the class of an LI to active when a variable I have matches the contents of the HREF on an A within the LI.

It is structured as follows:

```
<li><a href="foo.html">Foo</a></li>
```

When my "page" variable is equal to "foo.html" I want to change the class of the li to active. As follows:

```
<li class="active"><a href="foo.html">Foo</a></li>
```

I know there is a moderately simple way of doing it, but the way I am doing it seems to be entirely wrong!

Just as a side note, it is worth bearing in mind (as this is where I have fallen over) that this is a menu, and there are numerous LIs e.g:

```
<li class="active"><a href="foo.html">Foo</a></li>
<li><a href="bar.html">Bar</a></li>
```

Many thanks,
Kris

Comment: Can you update with what code you have? It'll be more beneficial for you than one of us just posting a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('a[href="foo.html"]').closest("li").addClass("active");
```

To work with your page variable:

```
$('a[href="' + hrefVariable + '"]').closest("li").addClass("active");
```

**EDIT:**

To explain how this works:

- The first section, $('a[href="foo.html"]') will locate any and all links on the page with the href value of foo.html.
- The second object, .closest("li") will locate the closest li from the element found in the first section.
- The third object adds the class to the preceding element, in this case the li.

Comment: That works well, thank you :) What would be the correct way to use a variable where "foo.html" is in there, I tried concatenating it in but it threw up.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1: Getting the correct link element**

First you need to locate the correct `a` tag element, you can do that with the following [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
var href = "foo.html";
var a = $("[href='" + href + "']");
```

---

**Step 2: Getting the parent list item element**

Then you can find the direct parent using the [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) function:

```
var li = a.parent();
```

If it is not a direct parent, you can use the [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) function which will allow you to find the first ancestor that matches the supplied selector. For example:

```
var li = a.closest("li");
```

---

**Step 3: Changing the class**

Finally, you can add a class to any given element using the [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) function:

```
li.addClass("active");
```

if you need to remove the class at any point, or remove an existing class, you can use the [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) function:

```
li.removeClass("active");
```

NOTE: If you want to 'reset' all active list elements, you can easily do the following:

```
$("li.active").removeClass("active");
```

---

**The end result**

[Here is a working example in action](http://jsfiddle.net/9fKqH/)

Answer (score 0):

Although you didn't specify it in your question, I assume you'll want to remove the active class from other LIs?

```
var li = $('.menuClass li'), // menuClass is whatever the class of your menu is (or #menuId for id)
    page = 'foo.html';

li.each(function () {
    var t = $(this); // better performance
    t.removeClass('active'); // remove active class from all
    if (t.find('a').attr('href') === page) { // if the href equals the value of your page variable, add active class
        t.addClass('active');
    }
});
```